# When the system suspends, later not awake just restart

Tags: suspend

I have a problem with I put the system in suspend mode when I try to resume, Ubuntu reboot.
This not happened with previous version (15.10, etc.)

Why is happening this?
Where can I find the log to fix it?

Thanks

Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Answer (score 0):

Your swap partition should be large enough in order to hold all the information your system needs to suspend/hibernate and wake up.

https://wiki.debian.org/Swap is a good reading and mentions:

**Things to consider when deciding how to setup swap space on your machine**

Do you intend to use the Hibernate and Suspend functions? **If you intend to use either, you will need to ensure your available swap space is large enough to hold all information your running system will have in RAM.** If you intend to use Hibernate you should ensure that your Debian installation has access to a swap partition or file that is NOT shared with another instance of GNU/Linux.

Comment: All right, but I have a swap partition with 8.4GiB and the PC has just 4GiB so that is not the matter